# how can upload audio file to the server(mysql database) by using phonegap.?

Tags: php, android, cordova

Can anyone provide me a good help in reference of my question.  i want to upload a mp3  file to my server. my mp3 file is stored in my sd card.i want this help in phonegap. and i am using php in server side.

Comment: mario sir why did you cut my marks..? is anything wrong here..?

Comment: I've removed your obnoxious formatting and the pointless footer. Both are not appreciated here. Rather put some effort into making your questions understandable, and less broad inquiries of tutoring.

Comment: mario sir thank you for it. but as a good person you should not decrease my marks. please...

Comment: If by marks you mean downvotes, then you're misinformed. Downvotes are specifically for poor questions which show a lack of research and effort or are generally unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can start from learning:

[PHP Tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/article/627)

[MySQL tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/)

[Audio/video converting](http://ffmpeg.org/)

[Linux tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=linux%20tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=T37&channel=fs&source=hp&q=linux%20beginner%20tutorial&pbx=1&oq=linux%20beginner%20tutorial&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3038l4108l0l4303l9l8l0l0l0l7l319l1596l0.2.4.1l7l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=b39bfbe6a4b47d32&biw=1280&bih=877)

[Server to server data trasnfare](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/38b012c0-442a-491c-aafc-c174b0048546.mspx?mfr=true)

I think thats all you need.

Answer (score 0):

see my answer on your other question for details on how to transfer the file:

[how can upload mp3 file to the server(xxampp) by using phonegap.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171496/how-can-upload-mp3-file-to-the-serverxxampp-by-using-phonegap)

Comment: london sir please check my updated queation. i am following same path as you suggested me.