# how can upload mp3 file to the server(xxampp) by using phonegap.?

Tags: cordova

Please suggest me how can upload audio file to the server by using **phonegap**.?

I want to make a file browse option by which user provide the location of file which
is to be uploaded.

After pressing submit button file should be save in mysql data base on server  side.
i am using php for server side storing data.

You can provide me links which may be helpful to get some knowledge related to this 
work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can POST a file to your server from PhoneGap, here's the api with a pretty solid example:

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Then you can use PHP (or anything else) to pick up that POST and do whatever you want, save data as sql, write files, etc.