# how to upload audio file?

Tags: cordova

im using build.phonegap , and i want to record Audio then upload audio file to server .

i have seen the following code to record MP3:

```
function recordAudio() {
var src = "myrecording.mp3";
var mediaRec = new Media(src,
 function() {            console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");    
    },

 // error callback        function(err) {   
         console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: "+ err.code);      
  });

  // Record audio    mediaRec.startRecord();}
```

======================================================================================

this is for recording media file , now how i can upload this file to server ??

i have seen phonegap example to upload file to server  , but this example explain how to upload images from camera to server not mp3 file  , but i want to know how i can upload this mp3 file direclty to server .

and please i want to know :

**"myrecording.mp3"** file will saved inside my **application**  ????

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread: [how can upload mp3 file to the server(xxampp) by using phonegap.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171496/how-can-upload-mp3-file-to-the-serverxxampp-by-using-phonegap)

Which leads you to: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Comment: If everything is working fine now it would be nice to accept the answer so that others can see that it's the solution.